# How to check elasticksearch health with different metrics in single API call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, metrics

I need to read following elasticksearch metrics

1. Version
2. Up-time
3. No. of Jobs
4. Overall Health
5. No. of Nodes
6. Disk Available in %
7. JVM Heap Size
8. No. of Indices
9. Primary Shards
10. Replica Shards

in ASP.Net MVC application. My question :-
Is it possible to read all above metrics with one API call in elasticsearch?

I have written following method

```
private static string CheckESHealth()
    {
        string esurl = "http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health";
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        string strReturnVal = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            var response = httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(esurl)).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var esdata = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(esdata))
                {
                    JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(esdata);
        //as a example i have taken only status.. but i need all paramters mention above
                    strReturnVal = jobject["status"].ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                strReturnVal = "Errored : Received status code : " + response.StatusCode;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strReturnVal = "Errored : " + ex.Message;
        }

        return strReturnVal;
    }
```

in above example i am using :-  GET _cluster/health command which give following result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTVMM.png)

but i am trying to read all above metrics in one API call

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. We're happy to help you get your solution working, though. Please show us what you've tried. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to read above[in question] mentioned metrics in one query. so, i used following queries to get metrics.

1. http://localhost:9200/_cat/health?h=cluster,status,node.total,shards,pri,relo&format=json
2. http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?h=version,uptime,heap.percent&format=json
3. http://localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?h=disk.percent&format=json